# Format entire drive except windows operating system

Tags: windows-7, format

On my laptop windows is installed on C: and there are lot of empty folder and unwanted files which I need to delete. So I prefer formatting the entire drive C: without the need to reinstall OS.

In short, how do I format the entire drive but still have the operating system?

Comment: Probably you cannot, formatting means to get rid of all data on given partition.

Comment: yep, without backups of a pre-cluttered state, there’s no way to accomplish this task without either a rebuild, or manually decluttering the stuff you don;t want to see any more. if you have backups you can try restoring from a point early in the laptops lifetime.

Comment: Can't you just delete the unwanted files and folders?

Comment: @Indrek there are too many files to delete and at different folders even in the program files. I just need to flush out everything.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do this. A format basically removes everything on a drive (to clarify, drive is not a harddrive, but a drive letter), no exceptions.

Aside of that, it is possible that folders you deem as unnecessary are required by the Operating System and should not be removed.

Your only option is to remove the files/folders manually.